# Blurred or transparent bottom of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to add some effect to background image that will blurring the image in the bottom. Like here on background image :

[image]

Does someone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not actually blurred, it's fading out to white. You can achieve this by putting a vertical gradient over the top of the image that goes from 100% opaque (alpha 1.0) white at the bottom to 0% opaque (alpha 0.0) white at the top.

There's a decent gradients tutorial here:
http://blog.apoorvmote.com/gradient-background-uiview-ios-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIView` with required `CGRect` and then add your `UIImageView` as subview to the `UIView`. Now set some gradient color to `UIView`, this way you can achieve your requirement.